# Sign SSL certs with a master SSL cert

Tags: iis, ssl, ssl-certificate, iis-7

We have just been granted a wildcard SSL certificate for a sub-domain that we manage (e.g. *.service.test.com).

Rather than use this certificate on all of our IIS servers, I have been asked to use this certificate to sign certificates for each of our servers.

I've tried some Googling on this topic but I can't find anything.  Does anyone know if this is possible and if so how to do it?

We're running Windows Server 2008 with IIS 7.

Comment: I would contact the provider of the wildcard SSL certificate for assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certificates contain a usage restriction. Common certificates you get from a CA only contain the usage flag for using the certificate for authentication and purposes - hence to use it with SSL/TSL. For creating sub-certificates and sign them with the one you have you need a special certificate which can be used as intermediate CA certificate. 
Such certificates are much more expensive than regular certificates and you have to make provide a special hardware infrastructure and do a lot of certifications before you can get it.

Conclusion: I doubt that the certificate you have can be used to issue certificates.

Answer (score 3):

Certificates you get from a CA can not be used to sign other certificates.